# get admin credentials from liferay while using hsql database

Tags: mysql, liferay, liferay-6, hsqldb

I need to recover admin username / password or at lest email address of the admin of liferay.
We have one instance running on HSQL database( I know not remanded). I need to get admin access of this server. How can I get Username from hsql.

I took the data folder from running server and copy in local server. Given database connection string in portal-ext.properties file. and restart the server. Users from previous server does not gets imported in my local database.

Is there any mechanism from which I can able to import user from hsql to mysql or read hsql database by any mechanism.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access to HSQL with a database explorer like SQUIRRELL SQL and HSQL jdbc driver.

More info => [HSQLInspect](https://www.liferay.com/es/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/HSQLInspect)

Then you can edit users table to change admin password to something like "qUqP5cyxm6YcTAhz05Hph5gvu9M=" (this corresponds to test word). More info => [Lost admin password](http://www.liferay.com/es/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/89813).

Comment: Hay thanks for responding. Is any way to import HSQL database to MYSQL?

Comment: Yes! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27901304/liferay-migrate-data-from-hsql-to-mysql Don't forget to vote!

Comment: The users table is actually named `user_`

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution for this.

I just updated lportal file inside data/hsql file.

In lpotal, there is schema searched for the user_ table, modified two columns.
Encrypted password as 0.
Password as (custom password)

Liferay by default stores password into encrypted format. By setting Encrypted password to 0 allows you to set password in plain text.

restarted the server.

and It works.

Comment: Works, but I'd say mousesbelda's solution is a little nicer because of... you know, reasons.